# Смена цвета метки с помощью panTo

Tags: javascript

Имеется список адресов, например два адреса и две метки на карте, соответствующие этим адресам. При клике на адрес, карта перемещается на заданные координаты к соответствующей метке с помощью panTo. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе адреса, карта перемещалась по указанным координатам к указанной метке и метка сменяла свой цвет??

Answer (score 0):

ну, предлагаю такое решение.
При инициализации карты, т.е. при его отрисовке при загрузке, вам в `placemark` надо будет вставим кастомную картинку, например метка синего цвета. После, когда пользователь нажимает например на ссылку адреса, вам нужно будет написать скрипт на то чтобы, удалить метку с координат, заного поставить новую метку по координатам, только метка будет уже красного цвета. Ну и при последующем переходе на другой адрес перед удалением и отрисовкой, ставите чтобы на метке откуда перешли, тоже почистили и поставили метку синего цвета.